# Error: Evaluation error: argument of length 0. R Shiny 1:nrow

Tags: r, shiny

My file is one set of game data and PitchNo tells the pitch of the game. I am trying to generate plots of each batter's pitches seen in a game and I have labeled the PitchNo in the ggplot function. I want my plot for each batter to label the pitches seen, say 1-10, but instead it is still labeling them as the PitchNo of the game.

I added `Batter$PitchNo <- 1:nrow(Batter)` in my reactive filter. That line of code works in normal R but I cannot seem to find a way to make in work in a Shiny app.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
GameDataFile <- read_csv("GameDataFile.csv")
GameDataFile %>% group_by(PitchNo)
playerlist <- sort(unique(GameDataFile$Batter))

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId="Batter1",
        label="Player:",
        choices = playerlist)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("myZone")
    )))

server = function(input, output){
  output$myZone <- renderPlot({
    GameDataFile$PlateLocSide <- (GameDataFile$PlateLocSide * -1)

    newdata <- reactive({
      GameDataFile %>% filter(
      Batter %in% c(input$Batter1),
      Batter$PitchNo <- 1:nrow(Batter)) # Error is here 
    })

    ggplot(data = newdata(), aes(x = PlateLocSide, y = PlateLocHeight)) + 
      xlim(-2.5,2.5) + ylim(0,5) + scale_fill_viridis_c() + geom_point() +
      labs(x = "", y = "") + facet_wrap(~ Batter, ncol = 2) +
      geom_text(aes(label = PitchNo), vjust = -0.5) + theme_bw() +
      theme(strip.text = element_text(size=20, face="bold"))
  }, width=400, height=500)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: how many rows does your Batter have? Also, what class is Batter? add lines before that line with those questions to help troubleshoot

Comment: Your parentheses are bad. `Batter$PitchNo <- 1:nrow(Batter)` is *inside* `filter()`. You need to end the `filter()` before you add a new column. Or, since you're using `dplyr`, change the syntax to `filter(...) %>% mutate(PitchNo = row_number())`